# How to load a list of SVGs in React JS

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am storing a list of SVG's in an array. But for some reason they dont render. There is no error as well. I tried most of the solutions but none have worked for me. Any solutions?

My SVG Object:

In my data file:

```
const userList = [
  {
    miniLogo: `${require("../assets/logo/jim.svg")}`,
    name: "Jim",
    id: "0",
  {
    miniLogo: `${require("../assets/logo/Dana.svg")}`,
    name: "Dana",
    id: "1",
  }
];

export default userList;
```

Then somewhere in my component:

```
import users from "../../constants/users.map";

//Other Render Stuff
         <div>
          <Slider {...settings}>
            {users.map((user, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  style={{
                    background: "#FFFFFF",
                    boxShadow: "0px 20px 50px #EEF0F4",
                    borderRadius: "32px"
                  }}
                >
                  <img src={user.miniLogo} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </Slider>
        </div>
```

My Webpack Config:

```
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
    use: "file-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      "file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]",
      "image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug"
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: "svg-inline-loader"
  },
```

**UPDATE**

I remove the string literal from miniLogo as advised in the answers below.
But it still doesnt render. This is what I see.

[image: SVG Doesnt render]

My img tag after rendering:

[image: Image TAG]

Comment: can you give this a try:     <img src={require(`../assets/logo/${user. miniLogo}`)} alt="logo" />

Comment: Did you check the HTML, see if there's any `<img />` tag?
Could you render `user.miniLogo` instead of the `img` tag, see if contains the correct string?

Comment: Still didn't work. I updated my question

Comment: Does it render when you hard code the path. Otherwise its something to do with the svg.

Comment: What is the file name which contains `userList`?

Comment: Your code is just working fine. I think problem is with your import and export. Post your folder structure.

Comment: @ravibagul91 `users.map.js`

Comment: In the component where you imported the users, do `console.log(users)` and check if it print correct data.

Comment: @ravibagul91Yup it's printing correct data

Comment: @TabishJaved Okays so I tried to render the SVG's in a different project and it works. Looks like there is something wrong with my Webpack Config

Comment: Can you post your folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the line  `` miniLogo: `${require("../assets/logo/jim.svg")}` ``

It imported the svg syntax as string. So the img part became:

`<img src="<svg>...</svg>" />`

maybe you can try to remove the string literal:

```
const userList = [
    miniLogo: require("../assets/logo/jim.svg"),
    name: "Jim",
    id: "0",
  {
    miniLogo: require("../assets/logo/Dana.svg"),
    name: "Dana",
    id: "1",
  }
];
```

---

Update:

Hi, the image path does not contain `image/`, so it caused 404 issue.
I check your `webpack config`, and guess that's because `svg` was correspond to the first loader setting(with `ttf` and `eot` type).

Please just use only one loader setting for one file type, or it may cause this kind of problem.

Therefore, remove the `svg` type from first loader:

```
{
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
    use: "file-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      "file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]",
      "image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug"
    ]
  }
```

OR

If you want to load it inline  :

```
{
    test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
    use: "file-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
    use: [
      "file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]",
      "image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug"
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: "svg-inline-loader"
  },
```

Comment: It worked !!!!. However, I removed the svg-inline-loader and kept svg only in second loader

Comment: Glad to hear that !

Answer (score 0):

The SVG is just becoming a string. Can you give this a try

```
<img src={require(`../assets/logo/${user.miniLogo}`)} alt="logo" />
```

Do change the miniLogo path accordingly.